# GridView, Get Item's parent View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-adapter, android-gridview

I'm trying to send clicks to my child elements in `GridView` with a single touch event. So far, I can retrieve the data of the child element, but cannot perform a click on it.

Let me explain a bit more on the layout of things...

- `GridView` - Touch Event Handler here...

  - `LinearLayout` - onClick listeners here...

    - `TextView` - Just some text...

An adapter fills `GridView` with `LinearLayout`'s who have onClick events defined. These layouts contain `TextView`s where `TextView.setText("Some data from my dataset")`

I have an onTouch listener which is currently listening to touch events on the `GridView`, and is successfully finding the data of `TextView` depending on the position of the finger.

How do I get the `TextView`'s parent view, and call performClick at the user's finger position?

This is the current click handler, containing what I've got so far...
Assume `GridView` & `Adapter` are initialised properly...

```
@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
            switch(action)
            {
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) :
                int position = GridView.pointToPosition((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY());
                if (position != -1)
                {
                // I have looked at the other .get methods, and doing GridView.getXYZ (Where XYZ could be any method) and couldn't get anywhere...
                String item = Adapter.getItem(position);                    
                Log.d("TouchEvent","Action was DOWN/MOVE on " + item);
                return true;
                }
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) :
                Log.d("TouchEvent","Action was UP");
                return true;
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) :
                Log.d("TouchEvent","Action was CANCEL");
                return true;
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) :
                Log.d("TouchEvent","Movement occurred outside bounds " +
                        "of current screen element");
                return true;      
            default : 
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Also thought to mention, this `GridView` is contained within a fragment. I *doubt* it would change the world, but might affect the solutions you guys have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaahh.. Something we need to try,

Implement method like,

```
private View getViewByPosition(GridView gridView, int position) {
    int firstPosition = gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    int lastPosition = gridView.getLastVisiblePosition();

    if ((position < firstPosition) || (position > lastPosition))
        return null;

    return gridView.getChildAt(position - firstPosition);
}
```

Now, call this method,

```
if (position != -1)
{
    // I have looked at the other .get methods, and doing                  GridView.getXYZ (Where XYZ could be any method) and couldn't get anywhere...
    GridView gridView = (GridView) v;
    View touchedView = getViewByPosition(gridView, position);

    String item = Adapter.getItem(position);                    
    Log.d("TouchEvent","Action was DOWN/MOVE on " + item);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,`touchedView` returned the ID of the Child View. It also made me discover I mistakenly put the onClick on the text and not the view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v,
int position, long id) 

{ 
 // Send intent to SingleViewActivity 
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleViewActivity.class); 
// Pass image index 

i.putExtra("id", position);
 startActivity(i); 
}

 });

After this create SingleViewActivity.java class 
public class SingleViewActivity extends Activity 
{
 @Override 
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.single_view);

// Get intent data 
 Intent i = getIntent(); 
 
// Selected image id

 int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id"); 
 ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.SingleView); imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
 } 

}

Comment: Hi there, sorry but this question has been answered, also it looks like your answer revolves around using ImageAdapters, something which my application does not. Thanks for the response though.