# How do you evenly distribute children in GridView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

This question is related to my [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899586/gridview-get-items-parent-view) about getting the parent view of a child in a `GridView`, the setup has not changed dramatically. This `GridView` belongs in a fragment.

As in my other post, the layout is as follows:

- `GridView` - Inflates the following with an adapter...

  - `LinearLayout`

    - `TextView`

I am trying to get the children of this view to fill all the available space on the display. The scaling of the text at this point is unimportant.

The elements are normally arranged in a square grid, the count of which is supplied by `myObject.GridSize`

I have so far only tried changing the attributes in XML, with a failed attempt to modify the children's width/height after the adapter has filled it, the code of which is just ignored. I've also tried a test layout to get a small 6x6 grid of buttons to stretch evenly across the view using weights on the parent layouts, which is proving impossible.

Researching this issue has led me down to all kinds of unusual problems `android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"` made the views not generate, so I'm asking if any of you have seen this problem, and know the solution.

Comment: Impossiburu xD, it is not designed for this case. At least i came to this after a few days of unsuccessful tries. Try to use GridLayout instead.

Comment: Gah! The problem is I rely on GridView to figure out what item is underneath my finger. GridLayout doesn't have those kind of methods defined so it breaks more than it attempts to fix!

Comment: You can always implement missing parts. I recommend to look at source code of Android launcher for 4.0-4.4, it contains some sort of grid layout implementation that seemingly provides this functionality.

Comment: By `figure out what item is underneath my finger` do you mean onClick or hovering over it (like a gesture)? If the first issue, you should be able to solve that using the correct logic, for the latter I didn't even know GridView had that functionality to begin with :P

Comment: If you read my [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899586/gridview-get-items-parent-view) you'll see what I was aiming for. Essentially, the code in that post gets the view right where my finger is, and then performs a click on that child view. That logic though, relies on the information provided by GridView. Sadly, I don't have the time to start altering main classes/object so I'm just going to leave it where it is.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no clear solution within the android framework for this functionality (without hacking it to bits) for now I've had to succumb to defining individual layouts depending on the devices size (something of which I cannot stand).

Unless anyone (or if google) have a solution, please post anyway, and if it works, you'll be marked as the answer.

Thanks.